# Why does openssl operate in big endian format?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, endianness

Is there a specific advantage of big-endian-ness or limitation of little-endian-ness?

Comment: In what way does openssl "operate" in big-endian format? Give an example.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer.

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [more details](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities.

Comment: @JamesKPolk , by operate, I mean that its apis are written such that they accept/return numbers in big-endian format.

Answer (score 1):

In general, things "on the wire" use big endian, and things "on the chip" do whatever the chip wants (or do a lot of work to work around what the chip wants).

The main input/output flows of OpenSSL are DER (or BER) encoded ASN.1 data structures.  The BER encoding family uses big-endian, as it is mainly designed to be a wire/interop format.  Since the main flow is big endian, the intermediate data structures (like `BN`) importing and exporting in big-endian makes their DER import/export easier.  What they do under the covers is an implementation detail.

To contrast, Windows CAPI's easiest key import/export API uses a proprietary format which was (likely) designed to be easier to work with given their internal structure (little-endian since it was designed for the x86 processor).

During the revamp of Windows Cryptography which led to the Windows CNG libraries the import/export formats were changed to big endian.  One supposes the motivation was to look more like the wire formats (and other libraries' import/export formats) to reduce user confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @bartonjs:

[Network Byte Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking) is big endian, see [RFC1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700).

The way we write Arabic numbers is big endian, that is the most significant digits are on the left so one hundred twenty three is written 123, little endian would be 321.

If you put the int16_t representation of 1000 (decimal) 0x03e8 (hex) on a big endian machine the "0x03" is in the lowest addressed byte and the 0xe8 in the next higher ordered byte, the big end of the number 1000 is first. When displayed in a hex dump on a big endian device they are in natural order 0x03, 0xe8. When displayed in a hex dump on a little endian device they are in the order 0xe8, 0x03 and one needs to re-order them in one's head.

While few developers look at hex dumps any more there was a time that was not only frequently done but required.